# The page you requested was not found in login 404

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

i have a script login using php and codeigniter 3

this my controller with name *Auth.php*

```
private function _login()
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username', true);
        $password = $this->input->post('password', true);

        $user = $this->Auth_m->get_where('users', ['username' => $username])->row_array();
        if ($user != null) {
            if (sha1($password) == $user['password']) {
                $data = [
                    'username' => $user['username'],
                    'id_user' => $user['id_user']
                ];
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                redirect('admin/dashboard');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan', '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Password Salah!.</div>');
                redirect('auth');
            }
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan', '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Akun Belum Terdaftar!.</div>');
            redirect('auth');
        }
    }
```

this my model with name *Auth_m.php*

```
class Auth_m extends CI_Model
{
    public function get_where($table, $where)
    {
        return $this->db->get_where($table, $where);
    }
}
```

this my view with name login.php

```
<form class="form-signin" action="<?= base_url('auth'); ?>" method="post">
          <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Pembayaran SPP Sekolah</h1>
          <br>

          <?= $this->session->flashdata('pesan'); ?>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus>
            <small class="muted text-danger"><?= form_error('username'); ?></small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            <small class="muted text-danger"><?= form_error('password'); ?></small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Masuk</button>
          </div>
          <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; <?= date('Y'); ?></p>
        </form>
```

i was change redirect page and another script cannot find a problem, please help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Examine the html in teh browser and see what the **action** contains.  Is that a valid url ?